# Excel vba do while loop not recognizing the do while statement

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop

I am attempting to write a macro that checks each row in one sheet called raw data for a matching name and if the name matches, copy the data from that row over to a sheet called name search. I am attempting to do this using a do while loop similar to one that i have used successfully in the past.

However when I try to run it, it gives me the error "Loop without do" despite the fact that everything seems to be in the correct place. my code is as follows:

```
Sub NameSearch()

Sheets("Raw Data").Unprotect ("29745")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Long

'set starting point at row 2
x = 2

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet: Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name Search")

Do While sourceSheet.range("A" & x).Value <> ""

    If sourceSheet.range("O" & x).Value <> destSheet.range("B2") Then
        x = x + 1

    Else
    If sourceSheet.range("O" & x).Value = destSheet.range("B2") Then

'selects the next row where the 1st column is empty
            lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'pastes the data from the specified cells into the next empty row
            destSheet.range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("A" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("B" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("C" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("C" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("D" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("D" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("E" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("E" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("F" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("F" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("G" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("G" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("H" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("F" & x).Value - sourceSheet.range("G" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("I" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("M" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("J" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("N" & x).Value

        x = x + 1

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

I can not for the life of me figure out what I did wrong. Any help improving my code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need another End IF

Comment: im blind thank you so mich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `End If` ... see below

```
Sub NameSearch()

Sheets("Raw Data").Unprotect ("29745")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Long

'set starting point at row 2
x = 2

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet: Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
Dim destSheet As Worksheet: Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name Search")

Do While sourceSheet.range("A" & x).Value <> ""

    If sourceSheet.range("O" & x).Value <> destSheet.range("B2") Then
        x = x + 1

    Else
    If sourceSheet.range("O" & x).Value = destSheet.range("B2") Then

'selects the next row where the 1st column is empty
            lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'pastes the data from the specified cells into the next empty row
            destSheet.range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("A" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("B" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("C" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("C" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("D" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("D" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("E" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("E" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("F" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("F" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("G" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("G" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("H" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("F" & x).Value - sourceSheet.range("G" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("I" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("M" & x).Value
            destSheet.range("J" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("N" & x).Value

        x = x + 1

    End If
End If '<----MISSING END IF
Loop

End Sub
```